# Jenkins will not start

Tags: jenkins, centos

After installing `Java` and `Jenkins` on my `CentOS 7 server`. I tried to start the Jenkins, and I am getting the below error message.

> Job for jenkins.service failed. See "systemctl status jenkins.service"
> and "journalctl -xe" for details.

When I run "systemctl status jenkins.service" to see what the issue is, I get the below output

```
● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2022-08-18 14:23:02 UTC; 20s ago
  Process: 8847 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8847 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 18 14:23:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Aug 18 14:23:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
Aug 18 14:23:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
Aug 18 14:23:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 18 14:23:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Aug 18 14:23:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for jenkins.service
Aug 18 14:23:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Aug 18 14:23:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
Aug 18 14:23:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
```

Not quite sure how to fix this. Anybody with a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

can you please use `journalctl -xe` for more detailed logs.

also can you run Jenkins in interactive mode to see why its failing to start like -

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

you can get command details in /usr/bin/jenkins file.

Comment: Just simply run: /usr/bin/jenkins and see the results. May be wrong java version.