# "systemctl start jenkins.service" Fails

Tags: jenkins, centos, devops

I installed jenkins with java 11 and everything seemed to be set fine but when starting jenkins service the process fails with the following log that I got when I ran
"systemctl status jenkins-service"

What I get when I start jenkins : "systemctl start jenkins.service

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start jenkins.service
Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

This is the status I get when running "systemctl jenkins.service" :
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status jenkins.service

```
● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Wed 2022-11-09 23:41:16 UTC; 9s ago
  Process: 2605 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2605 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 09 23:41:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 09 23:41:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Nov 09 23:41:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
Nov 09 23:41:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
Nov 09 23:41:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 09 23:41:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Nov 09 23:41:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for jenkins.service
Nov 09 23:41:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Nov 09 23:41:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
Nov 09 23:41:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
```

Also I get this error log when i run "journalctl -xe"

```
[root@localhost ~]# journalctl -xe
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at executable.Main._main(Main.java:334)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at executable.Main.main(Main.java:116)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: 2022-11-10 00:09:52.467+0000 [id=1]        WARNING        winst
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: 2022-11-10 00:09:52.564+0000 [id=1]        INFO        winstone
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: %C/jenkins/war/META-INF/MANIFEST
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.jav
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.j
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.j
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at winstone.HostConfiguration.getWebRoot(HostConfiguration.java
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:85)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:65)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:44)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:182)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:403)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invo
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invo
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at executable.Main._main(Main.java:334)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at executable.Main.main(Main.java:116)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: 2022-11-10 00:09:52.565+0000 [id=1]        SEVERE        winsto
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: %C/jenkins/war/META-INF/MANIFEST
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.jav
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.j
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.j
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at winstone.HostConfiguration.getWebRoot(HostConfiguration.java
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:85)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:65)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:44)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:182)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:403)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invo
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invo
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at executable.Main._main(Main.java:334)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain jenkins[16798]: at executable.Main.main(Main.java:116)
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
-- Subject: Unit jenkins.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit jenkins.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
-- Subject: Unit jenkins.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit jenkins.service has finished shutting down.
Nov 10 00:09:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server...
-- Subject: Unit jenkins.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit jenkins.service has begun starting up.
```

Comment: You chopped the right hand side of the  "journalctl -xe" message, but it's something about "file not found"

Comment: [Same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73504401/598141)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, possibly because Jenkins requires a specific version of Java to run properly. Eventually, I uninstalled Jenkins and installed java-17-openjdk as per the official documentation, which resolved the issue.（https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/）

```
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.io-2023.key
sudo yum upgrade
sudo yum install fontconfig java-17-openjdk
sudo yum install jenkins
```

[the official documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3imJ.png)